# Exclude nodes using WHERE not works

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have an error when i try to exclude nodes using MATCH&WHERE

I have the next nodes & rrlationships:

```
MERGE (a1:accz {id: 1}) 
MERGE (a2:accz {id: 2}) 
MERGE (a3:accz {id: 3}) 
MERGE (a4:accz {id: 4}) 
MERGE (a5:accz {id: 5}) 
MERGE (i1:itemz {id: 1}) 
MERGE (i2:itemz {id: 2}) 
MERGE (i3:itemz {id: 3}) 
MERGE (i4:itemz {id: 4}) 
MERGE (a1)-[:AUTHOR]->(i1) 
MERGE (a2)-[:AUTHOR]->(i2) 
MERGE (a3)-[:AUTHOR]->(i1) 
MERGE (a3)-[:AUTHOR]->(i3) 
MERGE (a4)-[:AUTHOR]->(i4) 
MERGE (a4)-[:AUTHOR]->(i5) 
MERGE (a4)-[:AUTHOR]->(i5) 
MERGE (a5)-[:AUTHOR]->(i2) 
MERGE (a5)-[:AUTHOR]->(i5)
```

When i execute (I include in a explicit way the items with which the accz need have a relationship):

```
MATCH (a:accz)-[:AUTHOR]->(i:itemz) WHERE ({id: i.id} IN [({id: 3}), ({id: 4})]) RETURN a
```

i got the *accz* nodes (3,4,5), and is ok. But then i exclude some nodes using WHERE, like the next query:

```
MATCH (a:accz)-[:AUTHOR]->(i:itemz) WHERE ({id: i.id} IN [({id: 3}), ({id: 4})]) AND (NOT (a)-[:AUTHOR]->(:itemz {id:5})) RETURN a
```

but i continue getting the *accz* node id:5, this should be excluded because the acc{id:5} is AUTHOR of (:itemz {id:5})

what im doing wrong?

Comment: Please update your question with the cyphers you actually ran (or reproduced with). As it stands, it doesn't make any sense. The Create nodes part doesn't have an itemz 5, and even if it did, your first query wouldn't return it, nor would the extended version return it. As it stands, we can't reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

The odd behaviors seen in your example would seem like bugs, but can be explained (after some careful thought). One conclusion, after all is said and done, is that **you should avoid using unbound nodes in a `MERGE` clause**.

## The odd behaviors

Your creation query has no `MERGE` clause to create the `itemz` node `i5`. That is, this clause is missing: `MERGE (i5:itemz {id: 5})`.

1. Therefore, it would seem like the 2 `MERGE (a4)-[:AUTHOR]->(i5)` clauses should result in the creation of a new unlabelled `i5` node with no properties -- but no such node is created!
2. And it would also seem like the `MERGE (a5)-[:AUTHOR]->(i5)` clause should result in a relationship with that new `i5` -- but instead it unexpectedly results in a relationship with `i4`!

## Explanation

This snippet of code causes the odd behavior (I have added comments to clarify):

```
MERGE (a4)-[:AUTHOR]->(i4) // Makes sure `(a4)-[:AUTHOR]->(i4)` relationship exists
MERGE (a4)-[:AUTHOR]->(i5) // Matches above relationship, so creates `i5` and binds it to `i4`!
MERGE (a4)-[:AUTHOR]->(i5) // Matches same relationship, so nothing is done.
```

So, after the snippet is executed, `i4` and `i5` are bound to the same node. This explains the odd behaviors.

## Conclusion

To avoid unexpected results, you should avoid using unbound nodes in `MERGE` clauses.

If your creation query *had* included a `MERGE (i5:itemz {id: 5})` clause before the relationships were created, then your queries would have worked reasonably. The result of the first query would contain `accz` nodes 3 and 4, and the result of the second query would only contain 3.

*By the way, `({id: i.id} IN [({id: 3}), ({id: 4})])` can be greatly simplified to just `i.id IN [3, 4]`.*